# Read urls requested by any browser

Tags: java, proxy

I'm writing an application to test the implementation of our image within an HTML body.
For this I need to have all the URLs requested by the browser that is running on the client.

I've written a proxy so that the browser can connect through there and that the proxy does the requests. (Based on [jProxy](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/jProxy.java)).

Now this proxy server doesn't respond to HTTPS requests and most of our image's are requested through HTTPS. I've been looking at some other examples but most have fake certificates and lots of code to make it work. (Like [mitm](http://crypto.stanford.edu/ssl-mitm/), doesn't work for google.com :( )

Basically I was hoping if anyone knew if there was an easier way to get the URLs requested by the browser. All I need are the URLs response code's would be nice as well, but not required (bit like the net inspector in firebug), so that I can render a green light that the image has been successfully called.

The reason I need it in Java is because it's for a study assignment, otherwise I would've made a web-based page which then requests the URL for you (for example PHP & curl).

Comment: Right since https on proxy isn't possible i tought lets try javafx. Now i've got javafx running and got my own browser found the posibility to read events. But i can't seem to find the event that tells me what urls are being loaded in the content.

Basically i'm looking for a javafx net inspector (like firebug net inspector).

Comment: I actually found a working one called [Java Proxy](http://www.me.lv/jp/) [dowload here](http://www.me.lv/jp/jp3.jar). But it's compiled in a mumbo jumbo way that i can barely understand whats happening. Anyone know a way to make it more readable?